# How can I deploy salesforce project with apex class to enterprise account?

Tags: deployment, salesforce, force-ide

I've been working in a salesforce development edition environment and have built something that uses an apex page and an apex class. I'm now trying to deploy this to our company's salesforce account so they can test it out. We have an enterprise account, I believe. When I use "Deploy To Server" from ForceIDE, I enter the username, password and security token of a sys admin on the company account. In the screen where it shows me what it will deploy, the apex class is not checked and when I click on it, it says "Component Type not permissible in destination organization".

This is my first attempt at salesforce development and am stuck. I've read everything I could find on the subject but nothing has helpe. Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Just to be clear, my code is at 92% test coverage -- so that is not the problem.

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

You say you're using a system administrator username. Please double check that they are an admin, and more specifically, that they have the "Author Apex" permission checked on the user profile.

Answer (score 0):

Just check, are you using Admin profile or anything else?
And check with the **Administrative Permissions**

1. API Enabled
2. Author Apex

Both these should be checked.